# How can I center my text on top of an image, given that it's responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

The text is already on top of the image, but the image changes in size when you resize the page. How can you let the text adjust it's center to the height of the image?

This is what I got

HTML

```
<section id="eyeCatcher">
   <div id="catchContainer" >
       <div id="eyeCatchQuote">
        <h1>text</h1>
       </div>

       <span id="eyeCatchPhoto" role="img" >
           <span class="inner">
           </span>
       </span>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#eyeCatcher{
   max-width: 1366px; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
}

#catchContainer {
   max-width: 1366px; 
}

#catchContainer #eyeCatchPhoto {
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font: 0/0 serif;
   text-shadow: none;
   color: transparent;
   background-size: 100%;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#catchContainer #eyeCatchPhoto .inner{
   padding-top: 60%;
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
}

#catchContainer #eyeCatchPhoto{
   background-image: url("../img/overview.jpeg");
}

#eyeCatchQuote{
   margin-top: -26px; 
   position: relative; 
   top: 300px; 
}
```

And this is what it looks like

[Big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCvfu.png)

[Resize to small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe7Qq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a span with a background image you can use an actual image.Then it is possible to center the text using absolute positioning.

HTML:

```
<section id="eyeCatcher">
 <div id="catchContainer">
    <div id="eyeCatchQuote">
      <h1>TEXT ELEMENT</h1>
    </div>
    <img src="YOURIMage" id="eyeCatchPhoto" role="img">
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#eyeCatcher {
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#catchContainer {
  max-width: 1366px;
  position: relative;
}
#catchContainer #eyeCatchPhoto {
 width:100%;
}
#eyeCatchQuote {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left:50%;
 margin:0;
 transform:translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeaqyLup/)

Comment: You are a god! Thanks!

Comment: Just a small note, it should be "max-width: 100%"